# Reseed IDENTITY to First in case of ROLLBACK

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I have transaction which insert few rows into one table.

Let's say this: My table has maximum ID of 100, and then I need to insert another 100 rows, where at the finish maximum ID will be 200. Other transactions waiting my transaction to finish and they reserved number 201, regardless my transaction finish successfully or not.

Rollback transaction doesn't help to reseed ID to 100, because if I put identity statement outside transaction, other transactions have higher priority and they already reserved number 201.

Hos to reseed identity column to i.e. 100 if my transaction rollback, but before other transaction take next ID?

I am hope I was enough clear.

Comment: Don't use `IDENTITY` if you need a sequence with no gaps. It is not designed for this purpose. Why do you need this?

Comment: Also, in Sql Server 2012, [IDENTITY columns will increment by 1000 when the server is restarted](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-2012-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should do this.

I'm not sure how other transactions, waiting for yours to finish, have reserved 201.  They don't know that identities are being consumed; they only know that they're blocked.

In any case, there's no harm in having a gap in IDs.  This is how identity works.  You should not try to alter it.